# Django SMTPServerDisconnected error on password reset (but works elsewhere)

Tags: python, django, email, smtp

I'm trying to set up self-serve password resets on a django setup. I have configured it to use the in-built password reset system, and have tested everything on my dev machine, and works fine. However, in production (i.e. actually sending emails), when I try to get a password reset email, it throws an SMTPServerDisconnected error:

```
[22/Sep/2017 15:04:59] ERROR [django.request:256] Internal Server Error: /password_reset/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/srv/virtualenvs/sis_esv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 132, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/srv/virtualenvs/sis_esv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 145, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/srv/virtualenvs/sis_esv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 110, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/srv/virtualenvs/sis_esv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/views.py", line 182, in password_reset
    form.save(**opts)
  File "/srv/virtualenvs/sis_esv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/forms.py", line 256, in save
    html_email_template_name=html_email_template_name)
  File "/srv/virtualenvs/sis_esv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/forms.py", line 213, in send_mail
    email_message.send()
  File "/srv/virtualenvs/sis_esv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py", line 303, in send
    return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])
  File "/srv/virtualenvs/sis_esv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 107, in send_messages
    sent = self._send(message)
  File "/srv/virtualenvs/sis_esv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 123, in _send
    self.connection.sendmail(from_email, recipients, message.as_bytes(linesep='\r\n'))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 735, in sendmail
    self.rset()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 469, in rset
    return self.docmd("rset")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 394, in docmd
    return self.getreply()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 368, in getreply
    raise SMTPServerDisconnected("Connection unexpectedly closed")
SMTPServerDisconnected: Connection unexpectedly closed
```

I'm using G-Suite (Google) as the SMTP relay; the settings I'm using are:

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp-relay.gmail.com'  
EMAIL_PORT = 587                     
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

The weird thing is I can send emails fine in other places within the system, using django's django.core.mail.send_mail() function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem turned out to be that I hadn't set DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL, thus django was attempting to send from a localhost email address, which Google's SMTP servers silently rejected. In other uses for send_mail() I had specified the from address, so this didn't appear as an issue there.

Comment: I also had this problem, the `DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL` was different in my settings than what I had set up with my SendGrid Account.